# Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'T FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0' na linha 1

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, chave-estrangeira

Eu não manjo muito de banco de dados, logo, meu conhecimento em sql é mínimo. Um amigo me passou uma db para que eu a pudesse editar e atualizar os dados desta (coisa que me parece simples), mas ao tentar importar via phpMyAdmin ocorre o seguinte erro e, com isso, não consigo ter acesso ao restante do projeto:

Análise estática:

3 erros foram encontrados durante análise.

1) Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "T" at position 0)

2) Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS"

3) Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "0" at position 21)

Comando SQL:

T FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0

Mensagens do MySQL:

## 1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'T FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0' na linha 1